# Run the app ( Published on Apple Store ) on a real devices on different Mac device with the same Apple Account

Tags: ios, apple-developer-account

My account is Apple Developer Enrollment.
I'm having an React Native application using firebase and Apple Push Notification service (APNs) and I had release succesfully it on Apple Store.

Now, I want build my app `(with same bundle identifier ...)` on real Iphone device on another Macbooks (other member's Mac in my team). Ofcourse I can not give my teammate my Apple Developer account username and password.

So I have 2 question :

- How my teammate can build my application `(with same bundle identifier ...)` on their real Iphone device ?
- And how they can upload it into testfight ?

All I tried was to follow all steps in [this article](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-your-team/invite-team-members/) - add my teammate to development team with `Developer role`. But it not work, they can not build my app.

Comment: Did you grant the user the "access to certificates identifiers and profiles" additional permission? Are you using automatic signing for your app?

Comment: Yes, I did and I'm using automatic signing

Comment: Provide more details on the error they receive. "It doesn't work" is not very informative.

Comment: Sure,
https://i.ibb.co/5vRLMG9/Screenshot-2023-07-16-at-20-16-22.png

Comment: It looks like they haven't selected the correct team for signing. Make sure they have signed in to their Apple ID in Xcode settings and then select your organisational team. Xcode is trying to create the provisioning profile for your bundleid in a different team and it is failing because it is already registered (to your team)